# Highcharts: Force show a yAxis tick

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Let's take a basic demo line chart:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({  //all the code there
```

I want to force showing a tick on yValue=12.
How to achieve this?

I know about the plotLines and tickPositioner. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tickPositions (different than tickPoistioner) is my preferred method.

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions

If that does not fit your needs, you will need to explain in more detail what you want, and why these solutions don't work for you.

EDIT:

Another option, no less dirty, would be letting the main y axis set ticks as normal, and add a second y axis where you use the tickPositions setting to set the single 'new' tick that you need.

`example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/GJeth/

Not any less dirty really, but keeps the main process clean.

Comment: They do work for me, but, I'll have to calculate the ticks myself and it looks like a dirty fix

Comment: Yes, an option to simply add a tick to the precalculated ticks would be handy.  But right now it's either calculate them all, or let the chart calculate them all.  Probably worth adding a feature request:  http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general

Answer (score 1):

Third way is to use tickPositions. For example create second yAxis, which is linked to first one, and have `tickPositions: [12]` set.

Comment: I liked the idea, but there are two problems with it: 1. the value is shown to the left from the main tick value, 2. Still need to remove the nearest main axis tick(mainAxisTicks: [0,20,30], helperAxisticks[1] doesn't look well)

Comment: 1) Set offset: 0, for yAxis. 2) You mean overlapping 0 and 1 values? Then simple use `opposite: true` for second yAxis - label will be displayed on the right side of plotting area.